# Azure MSSQL connection lost intermitently

Tags: spring-boot, azure-sql-database, c3p0

I have created a spring boot microservice and using Azure MS-SQL for database.
For connectivity with database with I have used spring-jpa with following configuration

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://xxxxx:1433;databaseName=xxxx;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;
spring.datasource.username=xxx
spring.datasource.password=xxx
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
```

Whenever call to database is made, I get following exception intermittently which goes automatically if I retry again in sometime

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException:
   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError (SQLServerException.java190)
   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.checkClosed (SQLServerConnection.java388)
   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.getWarnings (SQLServerConnection.java2115)
   at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.getWarnings (NewProxyConnection.java807)
   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.handleAndClearWarnings (SqlExceptionHelper.java274)
   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logAndClearWarnings (SqlExceptionHelper.java254)
   at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.releaseConnection (LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java170)
   at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.close (LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java215)
   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.close (JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java193)
   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.close (SessionImpl.java421)
   at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl.close (EntityManagerImpl.java145)
   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor70.invoke
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java43)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java498)
   at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke (ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java347)
   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy151.close
   at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.closeEntityManager (EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java438)
   at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor.afterCompletion (OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor.java111)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.WebRequestHandlerInterceptorAdapter.afterCompletion (WebRequestHandlerInterceptorAdapter.java72)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExecutionChain.triggerAfterCompletion (HandlerExecutionChain.java169)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult (DispatcherServlet.java1059)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch (DispatcherServlet.java984)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService (DispatcherServlet.java901)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest (FrameworkServlet.java970)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet (FrameworkServlet.java861)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service (HttpServlet.java635)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service (FrameworkServlet.java846)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service (HttpServlet.java742)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter (ApplicationFilterChain.java231)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter (ApplicationFilterChain.java166)
   at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter (WsFilter.java52)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter (ApplicationFilterChain.java193)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter (ApplicationFilterChain.java166)
   at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal (ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java55)
   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter (OncePerRequestFilter.java107)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter (ApplicationFilterChain.java193)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter (ApplicationFilterChain.java166)
   at org.springframework.web.filter.ShallowEtagHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal (ShallowEtagHeaderFilter.java110)
   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter (OncePerRequestFilter.java107)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter (ApplicationFilterChain.java193)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter (ApplicationFilterChain.java166)
   at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.internal.WebRequestTrackingFilter.doFilter (WebRequestTrackingFilter.java86)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter (ApplicationFilterChain.java193)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter (ApplicationFilterChain.java166)
   at com.siemens.isb.lib.security.oauth.filter.RequestBasedInitializerFilter.doFilter (RequestBasedInitializerFilter.java33)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter (ApplicationFilterChain.java193)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter (ApplicationFilterChain.java166)
   at com.siemens.isb.lib.security.oauth.filter.ExceptionHandlerFilter.doFilter (ExceptionHandlerFilter.java28)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter (ApplicationFilterChain.java193)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter (ApplicationFilterChain.java166)
   at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal (WebRequestTraceFilter.java110)
   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter (OncePerRequestFilter.java107)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter (ApplicationFilterChain.java193)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter (ApplicationFilterChain.java166)
   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter (FilterChainProxy.java317)
   at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke (FilterSecurityInterceptor.java127)
   at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter (FilterSecurityInterceptor.java91)
   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter (FilterChainProxy.java331)
   at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter (ExceptionTranslationFilter.java114)
   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter (FilterChainProxy.java331)
   at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter (SessionManagementFilter.java137)
   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter (FilterChainProxy.java331)
   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter (AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java111)
   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter (FilterChainProxy.java331)
   at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter (SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java170)
   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter (FilterChainProxy.java331)
   at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter (RequestCacheAwareFilter.java63)
   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter (FilterChainProxy.java331)
   at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter (OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java176)
   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter (FilterChainProxy.java331)
   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter (LogoutFilter.java116)
   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter (FilterChainProxy.java331)
   at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal (HeaderWriterFilter.java64)
   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter (OncePerRequestFilter.java107)
   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter (FilterChainProxy.java331)
   at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter (SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java105)
   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter (FilterChainProxy.java331)
   at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal (WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java56)
   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter (OncePerRequestFilter.java107)
   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter (FilterChainProxy.java331)
   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal (FilterChainProxy.java214)
   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter (FilterChainProxy.java177)
   at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate (DelegatingFilterProxy.java347)
   at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter (DelegatingFilterProxy.java263)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter (ApplicationFilterChain.java193)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter (ApplicationFilterChain.java166)
   at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal (RequestContextFilter.java99)
   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter (OncePerRequestFilter.java107)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter (ApplicationFilterChain.java193)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter (ApplicationFilterChain.java166)
   at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal (HttpPutFormContentFilter.java108)
   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter (OncePerRequestFilter.java107)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter (ApplicationFilterChain.java193)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter (ApplicationFilterChain.java166)
   at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal (HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java81)
   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter (OncePerRequestFilter.java107)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter (ApplicationFilterChain.java193)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter (ApplicationFilterChain.java166)
   at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.TraceFilter.doFilter (TraceFilter.java164)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter (ApplicationFilterChain.java193)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter (ApplicationFilterChain.java166)
   at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal (CharacterEncodingFilter.java197)
   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter (OncePerRequestFilter.java107)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter (ApplicationFilterChain.java193)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter (ApplicationFilterChain.java166)
   at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal (MetricsFilter.java106)
   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter (OncePerRequestFilter.java107)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter (ApplicationFilterChain.java193)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter (ApplicationFilterChain.java166)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke (StandardWrapperValve.java199)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke (StandardContextValve.java96)
   at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke (AuthenticatorBase.java504)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke (StandardHostValve.java140)
   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke (ErrorReportValve.java81)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke (StandardEngineValve.java87)
   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service (CoyoteAdapter.java342)
   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service (Http11Processor.java803)
   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process (AbstractProcessorLight.java66)
   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process (AbstractProtocol.java790)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun (NioEndpoint.java1459)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run (SocketProcessorBase.java49)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java1149)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java624)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run (TaskThread.java61)
   at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java748)
```

I have used c3p0 datasource for making connections and above exception is logged by c3p0 as following

```
[c3p0] Another error has occurred [ com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection is closed. ] which will not be reported to listeners!
```

Please help on this for smooth connectivity.

Comment: It looks like your application is trying to work with (perhaps just to `close()`) a Connection that has already been `close()`d. The question is why. You don't list any c3p0 configuration here, but maybe a first thing to try would be to configure some Connection testing, most straightforwardly by setting c3p0's [testConnectionOnCheckout  to true](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#simple_advice_on_connection_testing). Your c3p0 config should be dumped into your logs at INFO when your DataSource is initialized. You can look there to see if any Connection testing is set up.

Answer (score 1):

When you're designing a real world cloud app, one of the things you have to think about is how to handle temporary service interruptions. This issue is uniquely important in cloud apps because you're so dependent on network connections and external services. You can frequently get little glitches that are typically self-healing, and if you aren't prepared to handle them intelligently, they'll result in a bad experience for your customers.

In the cloud environment you'll find that failed and dropped database connections happen periodically. That's partly because you're going through more load balancers compared to the on-premises environment where your web server and database server have a direct physical connection. In other cases you might be the user who is hitting the service too frequently, and the service deliberately throttles you – denies connections – in order to prevent you from adversely affecting other tenants of the service.

Instead of throwing an exception and displaying a not available or error page to your customer, you can recognize errors that are typically transient, and automatically retry the operation that resulted in the error, in hopes that before long you'll be successful. Most of the time the operation will succeed on the second try, and you'll recover from the error without the customer ever having been aware that there was a problem.

```
protected void handleTransientException(SQLException sqlE) 
        throws RetryPolicyException, SQLException { 

    // if no retries left throw exception 
    if (!isRetriesLeft()) { 
        throw new RetryPolicyException("Attempt to retry for " 
                + retryCount 
                + " times falied with " + waitingTime 
                + " millsecond interval"); 
    } 
    // Decrement the retries count 
    retriesLeft--; 
    if (isTransient(sqlE)) { 
        // Wait for specified time 
        waitForRetryInterval(); 
    } else { 
        // Its a Non transient exception Re throw the exception 
        retriesLeft = 0; 
        throw sqlE; 
    } 
}
```

For more information visit [this](http://www.javased.com/index.php?source_dir=azure4j-blog-samples/SQLAzure/JDBCRetryPolicy/src/com/persistent/azure/jdbc/retry/RetryPolicy.java) page. You can also visit [this](https://github.com/rgl/azure-content/blob/master/articles/sql-database/sql-database-connect-central-recommendations.md) documentation for connection recommendations.

Comment: Thanks @Alberto, following your suggestion I applied spring retry in my project for SQLServerException.

Comment: I am glad. Have a great day!